# How to resolve lock up after mouse click?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mouse, gpu

I have a Mac Book Pro Retina display running OS X Yosemite and recently it has started acting up.  Occasionally, upon a trackpad click, the machine stops responding, you can move the pointer, but the keyboard does nothing and clicking the trackpad does nothing.  Holding down Command-Option-Esc does nothing.  I'm only able to hold down the power button until it forces a reboot when this arises.  Upon boot, the machine reports a graphics error:

**A graphics problem has been detected.**

> Click "Report" to submit a report about this problem to Apple. This information is collected anonymously. You won't be contacted about this report.

I reported the issue.

I ran the Apple Hardware Test (not the extended version though), but no errors are reported.  Using an external USB mouse has the same issue.

How can I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: This is happening to me also. I think it has to do with switching between graphics cards, not clicking. Though it doesn't always happen, sometimes I've had it happen 3 or 4 times in a row. Pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have been corrupted non-volatile random-access memory — `NVRAM` (called Paramter RAM — `PRAM` on older Macs) as I reset the memory and after doing that, the problem went away.  On Intel-based Macs, the way to reset `NVRAM` is the same as resetting PRAM on older machines (as [explained by Apple support](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)):

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R.
3. Turn on your Mac.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
5. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
6. Release the keys.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround is to disable graphics switching: [image: Energy Saver preference pane with arrow pointing at Automatic Graphics Switcing]

Though this will affect battery life.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the console, what errors do you see reported? Do you see the phrase “mouse-down”? If so, I had a similar problem a few months ago which turned out to be caused by a 3rd party application called Numi. If you see the “mouse-down” phrase in Console, my advice would be to quit all 3rd party processes you might have running in the background from menubar items, etc. and add them back slowly, maybe one an hour, over the course of a day or so to see if you can catch the culprit.